# Django: how to model a rectangle?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to draw a rectangle using Django for backend and React for frontend. Some third party is going to hit my API with 4 coordinate points (x,y) in JSON format and then I draw the line via React. Should I keep a single model named Rectangle with 8 fields {(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)} or should I keep 2 models like:

```
class Rectangle(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Point(models.Model):
   rectangle = models.ForeignKey(Rectangle, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   x1 = models.FloatField()
   y1 = models.FloatField()
   def __str__(self):
      return '{} , {}'.format(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
```

If I keep 2 models, then writing serializers and class based views to handle the provided data will get a bit complicated. What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are sure that model will always have 4 points — I'd recommend use one model, containing 4 points coordinates. The way with point model connected to shape model via FK is cool too, because you can easily have as much points as you need.

Comment: Are you going to index the points data somehow? Or do any spatial queries? If not, everything can be simply stored as JSON data. IMHO storing points to an individual table is an overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using one simple model. If you are not building a new rectangle engine or something sophisticated, it will be enough.

As @BasicWolf already said in comment, you can even think of putting the points in just one field as JSON, or more simpler, comma separated (provided you never need to query for the points). Then when retrieving the points, just use split to extract the pairs and return that via API.